# vector and DataFrame length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I had a dataframe which consisted of 12 columns. Then I cut one vector from it and made it separate. I then performed train_test_split from sklearn library like below:

```
X=pd.DataFrame()

X['annua_inc']=annual_inc
X['delinq_2yrs']=delinq_2yrs
X['dti']=dti
X['emp_length']=emp_length 
X['loan_amnt']=loan_amnt
X['installment']=installment
X['int_rate']=int_rate
X['total_acc']=total_acc
X['open_acc']=open_acc 
X['pub_rec']=pub_rec
X['acc_now_delinq']=acc_now_delinq
X['loan_stat']=loan_stat

X=X.fillna(0)
y=X['loan_stat']
X=X.drop(['loan_stat'], axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=42)
```

When I check the length of for example X_test and y_test (which both should be the same) it returns me the same value. But when I try to call X_test[len(X_test)] it tells me that index is out of bounds for axis 0. But for y_test[len(y_test)] it gives me a correct value. Does anyone know why? because the last row in X_test and last row in y_test were previously combined in the same row in X so why now the last row for X_test doesn't exist and for y_test it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrays in python, pandas, numpy, scipy, and others are zero based in their indexing.  So the length of `[0, 1, 2, 3]` is 4.  But `[0, 1, 2, 3][4]` will be out of bounds.  Refer to the last element as either `[0, 1, 2, 3][4 - 1]` or `[0, 1, 2, 3][-1]`

In your case

```
X_test[len(X_test) - 1]
```

Or

```
X_test[-1]
```

Comment: Ok, but what about y_test which is of the same length as X_test and returns a value. But y_test is a vector, not array, so maybe this is the case?